# Laravel ::__construct() must implement interface

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `Laravel 5.4` And I'm trying to inject a `$order` class into a `trait` that's going to implemented by a `model`. Like this:

```
class Forum extends Model
{
    use Orderable;
```

The `constructor` of the trait looks like this:

```
trait Orderable
{
    public $orderInfo;

    public function __construct(OrderInterface $orderInfo)
    {
        $this->orderInfo = $orderInfo;
    }
```

My service provider looks like this:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(OrderInterface::class, function () {
        return new Order(new OrderRepository());
    });

    $this->app->bind(OrderRepositoryInterface::class, function () {
        return new OrderRepository();
    });
}
```

The constructor of my `Order` class looks like this:

```
public function __construct(OrderRepositoryInterface $orderInfo)
{
    $this->orderInfo = $orderInfo;
}
```

But I receive the error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Forum::__construct() must implement interface Project\name\OrderInterface, array given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/Package/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 268
```

The `OrderRepository` class is implementing the `OrderRepositoryInterface`. The Order class is implementing the `OrderInterface` interface.

App\Forum is the model that uses the `Orderable` trait.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: `App\Forum` throws the error, but that isnt noted here.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I've made an update!

Comment: So while calling `app->bind(` the error shows up, here you have to dig in. Class declaration seems right. Or is something wrong with this statement: `must implement interface Project\name\OrderInterface` Is the namespace fully right?

Comment: Under witch fully namespace is the trait `Orderable`? -- forget this.  You have to check the use of namespaces. Do check declared classes with `var_dump(get_declared_classes());` at the end of a script.

Comment: I've checked all namespaces they are correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending `Model`. This class already has a `__construct` that you need to use. This `__construct` expects `array $attributes = []` as the first argument.

So in your `__construct` you also  need to have this as the first argument and pass this to the parent class:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [], OrderRepositoryInterface $orderInfo)
{
    $this->orderInfo = $orderInfo;
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

However you can work around using `__construct` in laravel using `boot`.

For example in a `Model`:

```
class Forum extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Or in a `Trait`:

```
trait Orderable
{
    public static function bootOrderableTrait()
    {
        static::created(function($item){
            // Do something
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. But then I receive: ```Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Forum::__construct(), 1 passed in /home/vagrant/Code/Package/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 268 and exactly 2 expected``` any idea?

Comment: What happens if you change your it to: `__construct(array $attributes = [], OrderRepositoryInterface $orderInfo = null)`

Comment: I updated my answer with a way to use `boot` instead of `__construct`

Comment: If I make it  ```= null``` it does not crash anymore. But then is ```$orderInfo``` empty. With your ```bootOrderableTrait``` example where/how do I instantiate the ```OrderRepositoryInterface``` that's being bound to ```OrderRepository``` class?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP it's not possible to have multiple constructors. If you will look to Model:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
```

it expect array. That's why I assume that somewhere in Model array passed to constructor instead of 'OrderInterface'.

Comment: So what I'm trying is not possible?

Comment: Maybe it's better to add setter method instead of overriding constructor in trait. Or extend class and override constructor there